# Ajax doesn't properly work: The success function is called but the page is being printed instead of the page callback results

Tags: 7, javascript, ajax

I am using AJAX in Drupal 7 to get data from the bounds of a map, serialize it as a string, and submit as post to server to be added as a filter for a view to make a display respond to changes in zoom and array bounds.

The success callback is called, but the data returned is not the result of the page callback function: The XHTML response in Firebug is the entire web page.

I would really appreciate to know what is preventing the page callback function value from being returned.

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.mapresults = {
attach: function() {
// Dynamically show  the marker nodes
 // first find the right map
$.each(Drupal.settings.getlocations, function (key, settings) {
// this is the one we want
alert("0");
if (1 == 1) {
  // an event handler on map zoom to check if the view results needs to be updated     
  on zoom 
  // hooking another event and checking zoom may work better.
  google.maps.event.addListener(getlocations_map[key], 'bounds_changed', function()
  {

    // count number of markers <= 10'
    // global_settings.mgr
    //mgr = new MarkerManager(getlocations_map[key]);

     //zoomcount = mgr.getMarkerCount(getlocations_map[key].getZoom());
     zoomcount = 10;
     if(zoomcount < 100){
         // get bounds
         marker_bounds = getlocations_map[key].getBounds();



     // calculate horizontal distance from bounds to get max  and min latitude and
     longitude for the for box
    // submit data with jquery get bounds etc.
    var marker_bounds_string = JSON.stringify(marker_bounds);

    // ajax link to submit data by post
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/mapresults',
        dataType: "json",                   
        data : {marker_bounds : marker_bounds_string},             
        success: function (data)    
 {document.getElementById('map_results').innerHTML = "success";},
        error: function (xmlhttp)  
 {document.getElementById('map_results').innerHTML = xmlhttp.status;}
        });


    }
     else{

     }
  });
}
});
}
};
}(jQuery));
```

This is the module code.

```
function mapresults_menu() {
  $items['ajax/mapresults'] = array(
    'title' => t('mapresults AJAX'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'mapresults_ajax',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}
function mapresults_ajax() {
// call back for display map options
drupal_exit();
$view = views_get_view('search');

// set display
$display_id = 'default';

// add filters from ajax
// float
$bounds_array = json_decode($_POST['marker_bounds'])

//get cordinates from bounds_array
$lat_min = $bounds_array[0][0];
$lat_max = $bounds_array[1][0];
$lon_min  = $bounds_array[0][1];
$lon_max = $bounds_array[1][1];

// add filters to view
$view->exposed_input['ubicacion_latitiude'] = $lat_min;
$view->exposed_input['ubicacion_latitiude_1'] = $lat_max;
$view->exposed_input['ubicacion_longitude'] = $lon_min;
$view->exposed_input['ubicacion_longitude_1'] = $lon_max;
```

Comment: what format are you trying to return the response from your callback page in?

Comment: Something is wrong in your code, or you are showing debugging code: Once you call `drupal_exit()`, Drupal doesn't execute the PHP code after that, since you cause Drupal to exit.

Comment: I was using drupal_exit for debug, Im trying to return JSON